# output json data dynamically from perl cgi

Tags: perl, extjs, cgi

I have a simple perl cgi that i use in my extjs project, written like this :

```
use JSON;

print "Content-type: application/json\n\n";

my $node_hash = {
data => [{
     "Week",1145,
         "Sev_Logged", "3_major"
},{
    "Week", 1146,
        "Sev_Logged", "4_minor"
}]};
print to_json($node_hash);
```

Which returns data written in json format that i use to generate a chart.
I also have a form which contains a combobox with values : "3_major" and "4_minor" corresponding to the "Sev_Logged" field.
Now what i want is, whenever the user chooses "4_minor", my perl cgi will only return week 1146, thus my chart will only contain data of week 1146.

Is this possible? How?
Thank you

Comment: I think you did not tell us everything. There is code missing, right? Where does your data come from? Are you using `strict` and `warnings`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know where your data is coming from, but you can do something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;
use JSON;

my $q = CGI->new;
print $q->header("application/json");

my $Sev_Logged = $q->param('Sev_Logged');

my $data = [
  {
    "Week" => 1145,
    "Sev_Logged" =>"3_major",
  },
  {
    "Week" => 1146,
    "Sev_Logged" => "4_minor",
  },
];

my $node_hash = {
  data => [
    grep { $_->{'Sev_Logged'} eq $Sev_Logged } @$data,
  ]
};
print to_json($node_hash);
```

You can call it like this: `GET script.pl?Sev_Logged=3_major`

---

Anyway, I think if you already transmitted all the data, you should filter it on the client side using JavaScript only. There is no AJAX call necessary in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks, this is what i wanted. Could you please tell me how to send that param to my cgi file? Normally i would do something like : Ext.Ajax.request({
   url: 'data/data.pl',    // where you wanna post
   params: { Sev_Logged }  // your json data
});

Comment: Just add them as GET params. Perl's CGI does not distinguish between GET and POST the way e.g. PHP does. It should look something like this:  `Ext.Ajax.request({ url: 'data/data.pl?Sev_Logged=' + Sev_Logged });`

Answer (score 1):

I would [`use CGI`](https://metacpan.org/module/CGI) to assist with this.  In short, you need to pass the combobox field to this CGI script via a form and a GET or POST request.  This CGI script then needs to read in the value of the combobox via the parameters.  If you use the CGI module, you can get the parameters via the `param` method.